# Issue with VSC (Zero knowledge of coding)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a total newbie to coding so I might need some dummy proof guidance. Basically, I am learning how to code from a course that I am taking (online course so I have no one to ask). I use a Mac Air and the course started with teaching me how to access the terminal and then downloading python 3 from python.org. This is where I encountered my first issue. The trainer types 'python' and it runs python 3 but I have to type 'python3' for that to happen. At this stage, I still can proceed.

However, we are told to download visual studio code (VSC) and I downloaded the python extension. I was also taught how to access the terminal through VSC. However, the trainer then proceeds to type 'python test.py' in the integrated terminal in VSC and it provides an output. However, when I do the same, it provides me an error:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'blockchain.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I thought it was cause it need to type 'python3 test.py' and the error changed but it is still the same:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/Aven/block.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I am not sure why this is not working. If there is a fix, again, I literally took this like 4 hours ago so my knowledge is literally zero so I would appreciate an answer than helps me dumb it down a lot. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that the error is related to your code or environment. Itś difficult to help you with your environment issues, but at least you should copy your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code I run is irrelevant in this case. I merely follow what my trainer does. But it does seem that it is indeed an environment issue. I realise that when my test.py file is placed in the "user" folder, my code runs with "python3 test.py". I will roll with that first till I get a better understanding of how the different platforms interact with each other. If you have an idea on how I can change where the terminal actually "finds" the file, please do let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Could be relavant if your code have soething like `import block` or `ìmport blockchain`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.